# I require use Laravel cashier with different model rather than to use default User model

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I am working on a property site, where users can signup for free, once they have complete their registration then they can post their property/job that they want to rent or sell out. One user can post multiple offices or houses as a property for sale/rent, but each job post/property requires a monthly subscription on a recurring basis. In the database, I have two tables one for users (users_table) and another for the user's property(users_property_table), both tables have primary and foreign relations with user_id.

I want to use the laravel cashier package with (users_property_table) not with the default one (Users), as per my understanding if I use the cashier package with the Users model than subscription will depend only User model, but in my case scenario is different, each job post or property need subscription before publishing to the site because job post is a paid service. can you please guide me on how I can achieve this functionality in laravel by using laravel cashier?

Comment: I dont think it is possible at the moment to use billable traits on different models using cashier. The only think You could do is build your own way to deal with subscription. Cashier works only with users, because the subscription table is related to user_id and stripe customer id is stored in users table.

Comment: Therefore, it is not possible with cashier alone. You will need to do it yourself. Build migration, attach customer id to different models. And then use php stripe to deal with all subscription traits.

Comment: yes, laravel mentioned in official documentation, how we can use the billable trait in a different model rather than use in the default one User, but they are not providing complete documentation, if you have any link or description (tutorial) please share it

Comment: here is a tutorial : 

https://swapnil.dev/blog/how-to-configure-laravel-cashier-with-multiple-models/